# Write a lazy sequence of lines to a file in ClojureClr without reflection

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

I have a large lazy seq of lines that I want to write to a file.  In C#, I would use `System.IO.File/WriteAllLines` which has an overload where the lines are either `string[]` or `IEnumerable<string>`.

I want to do this without using reflection at runtime.

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn spit-lines [^String filename seq]
  (System.IO.File/WriteAllLines filename seq))
```

But, I get this reflection warning.

> > Reflection warning, ... - call to WriteAllLines can't be resolved.

In general I need to know when reflection is necessary for performance reasons, but I don't care about this particular method call.  I'm willing to write a bit more code to make the warning go away, but not willing to force all the data into memory as an array.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options to consider, depending on whether you are using Clojure's core data structures.

#### Convert from a seq to an `IEnumerable<string>` with `Enumerable.Cast` from LINQ

This option will work for any `IEnumerable` that contains only strings.

```
(defn spit-lines [^String filename a-seq]
  (->> a-seq
       (System.Linq.Enumerable/Cast (type-args System.String))
       (System.IO.File/WriteAllLines filename)))
```

#### Type Hint to force the caller to supply `IEnumerable<string>`

If you want to use a type hint, do this.  But watch out, **the clojure data structures do not implement `IEnumerable<String>`, so this could lead to a runtime exception**.

```
^|System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]|
```

Wrapping the full CLR name of the type in vertical pipes (`|`) lets you specify characters that are otherwise illegal in Clojure syntax.

```
(defn spit-lines [^String filename ^|System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]| enumerable-of-string]
  (System.IO.File/WriteAllLines filename enumerable-of-string))
```

Here's the exception from `(spit-lines "filename.txt" #{})` when passing a set to the type-hinted version:

> > System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'clojure.lang.PersistentTreeSet' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.

More information about [specifying types](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-clr/wiki/Specifying-types).